# X-Telegram-Bot-Api-Secret-Token not present in headers

Tags: telegram

First, I have deleted my webhook:

```
curl "https://api.telegram.org/bot6359000876:XXX/deleteWebhook"
```

Then, I have set my webhook:

```
curl "https://api.telegram.org/bot6359000876:XXX/setWebhook?url=https://XXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/development/webhook&secret_token=abc"
```

When I check for the X-Telegram-Bot-Api-Secret-Token in incoming request from Telegram, the header is not present.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Telegram does not update the "setWebhook"; I had to delete the webhook and add it again to work.